# how come web3 send does not require a private key or signature

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20

I'm building an `ERC20 smart contract` which will be accessed via `node.js` with `web3` library.
I see that `web3.eth.Contract` has the `send` function, which takes the parameter `from`, which is being mapped to the `msg.sender` in the smart contract.
As far as I understand (and my debugging supports that), I can change the `from` field to just about any address, and by that bypass the business logic of the contract, e.g

```
token.methods.method_only_owner_can_activate(<some_data>).send({ from: <contract_owner_address>, <gas> });
```

or even set the owner:

```
token.methods.setOwner(<my_not_owner_address>).send({ from: <contract_owner_address>, <gas> });
```

since the address should be public, any user can create a process which mimics this behaveiour and bypasses my security logic.

There are other methods which **do** sign a transaction with the `private key`, but the fact that the `send` method is open for bypassing the business logic, seems like a big security concern.

As I missing something?

Comment: You are missing the fact that your `contract_owner_address` is unlocked on the Ethereum node that you are connected to. Either you are (unknowingly) unlocking it in your code, or the node is (unknowingly) unlocking it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any transaction to an actual Ethereum blockchain needs to be signed with a private key.

For the above code to work (just supplying a `from` address), the node you're connected to must be doing the signing for you. As long as the `from` address is "unlocked" in that node (the default under a test network like `ganache` or done explicitly using a normal node like geth or Parity), it's able to sign the transaction with that key and send it.

In a real-world situation, users of your app wouldn't be connected to a node that had your private key, so this is not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

The `web3` library creates a transaction that needs to be signed by the account specified in `from`. It is signed either by talking to a local node which has the private key to that account and currently has it unlocked, or by a piece of software like Metamask which controls that private key and only signs the transaction if the user confirms.

It is not possible to send a valid (signed) transaction without the private key of the account in the `from` field.

Answer (score 1):

The `msg.sender` property can't be faked - at least to the extent that someone can't create a transaction with a `msg.sender` which isn't an address they own.

Whatever security measures you have in your contract, you can rely on the fact that the `msg.sender` address is the person making the transaction.