# why does web3.eth.Contract.METHOD.send not need a private key for signing?

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to figure out why the web3 contract api does not need to sign the transaction, and only needs a `from` input to interact with the blockchain

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-send

What is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node you're connecting to is actually doing the signing for you (as long as the `from` address is unlocked), that's why only web3.eth.contract.METHOD needs a `from` parameter to interact with the blockchain.

See: [how come web3 send does not require a private key or signature](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57934/how-come-web3-send-does-not-require-a-private-key-or-signature)

Comment: would you know if is there a way to sign it manually with web3? how would other people interact with the method if their address is not unlocked?

Comment: @zcaudate You'll need to use signTransaction method of web3. Then use the output as argument to sendSignedTransaction.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html#signtransaction

Comment: @ShariqHasanKhan How would I do that with a contract method though?

Comment: the transactionObject (first argument to the signTransaction method) has a data field. Set it to your contract's concerned method.
=>  
data: YourContract.methods.ConcernedMethod(arg1, arg2, ...argN).encodeABI()